Facing issue console.error Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes) while runing jest test cases
public saveCSV(fileName: string, csvData: string): Observable<boolean> {
const exportedFilenmae = fileName + '.csv';
const blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });

const link = document.createElement('a');
if (link.download !== undefined) {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.setAttribute('href', url);
  link.setAttribute('download', exportedFilenmae);
  link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  this.complete = true;
  return of(this.complete);
}

}
}
whe ever I am injecting this kind of download I am getting the above error
I want to remove the error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
